# Bloquear o enter caso a textarea esteja vazia

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando verificar se uma `textarea` tem texto válido. Verificar o espaço foi fácil, mas o `enter` não sei como verifico.

```
enviar() {
    var num = 13; // 13 é o cód ascii do enter
    if (this.textoEmEdicao == '' || this.textoEmEdicao === " ") { // verifico se o texto é nulo ou tem espaço
      this.textoEmEdicao = '';// setar a textbox para nenhum texto
    } else {
      let mensagem = {
        texto: this.textoEmEdicao,
        data: new Date(),
        contato: this.emissor
      }
      this.adicionarMensagem(mensagem);
      this.textoEmEdicao = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Creio que a questão não é nem bloquear o Enter. Vc quer bloquear o Enter por qual motivo? O que essa função `enviar()` faz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para verificar** pode usar regex `/\S/.test(textarea)`

**Para bloquear** pode usar a resposta do @fernandosavio

**1 - vazio**

```js
var textarea=document.getElementById("demo").value;

if(/\S/.test(textarea)) {
   console.log('valido');
}else{
   console.log('não válido');
}
```

```html
<textarea id='demo'></textarea>
```

**2 - com espaço**

```js
    var textarea=document.getElementById("demo").value;

    if(/\S/.test(textarea)) {
       console.log('valido');
    }else{
       console.log('não válido');
    }
```

```html
<textarea id='demo'> </textarea>
```

**3 - com quebra de linha**

```js
     var textarea=document.getElementById("demo").value;

     if(/\S/.test(textarea)) {
        console.log('valido');
     }else{
        console.log('não válido');
     }
```

```html
<textarea id='demo'> 


</textarea>
```

**4- com algum conteúdo**

```js
     var textarea=document.getElementById("demo").value;

     if(/\S/.test(textarea)) {
        console.log('valido');
     }else{
        console.log('não válido');
     }
```

```html
        <textarea id='demo'>
        
        x 


        </textarea>
```

> `/\S/.test(textarea)` retorna true se e somente se houver um caractere não-espaço

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava, você ainda conseguiu juntar todas as respostas em uma só, vai poupar o tempo de muitas pessoas, parabens!

Answer (score 2):

Use `preventDefault`

**Definição e Uso**

O método preventDefault () cancela o evento se ele for cancelável, o que significa que a ação padrão que pertence ao evento não ocorrerá.

Por exemplo, isso pode ser útil quando:

- Clicando em um botão "Enviar", evite que ele envie um formulário
- Clicar em um link impede que o link siga o URL

Nota: nem todos os eventos são canceláveis. Use a propriedade [cancelable](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_cancelable.asp) para descobrir se um evento é cancelável.

> **Nota**: O método preventDefault () não impede a propagação adicional de
>   um evento por meio do DOM. Use o método stopPropagation () para lidar
>   com isso.
>
> **Fonte**: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

**Exemplo**:

```js
function blockEvent(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13 && document.getElementById("txt").value === "") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" cols="40" rows="5" onkeypress="blockEvent(event, this)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer saber se o `textarea` contém apenas espaços é melhor apenas usar a função [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) e checar se ela não é vazia.

O `trim` remove qualquer espaço em branco do início e do fim de uma string, seja ele quebras de linhas, tabs, espaços, etc...

```js
let text = document.getElementById('teste');
let feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

text.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  // retira todos os espaços do início e do fim
  let trimmed = this.value.trim();
  
  // se for vazio mostra erro e apaga o conteúdo.
  if (!trimmed) {
    this.value = '';
    feedback.innerHTML = "textarea vazio";
  } else {
    // se estiver OK remove o erro
    feedback.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
#teste {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="teste"></textarea>
<span id="feedback"></span>
```